# AngularJS decimal input: change comma to dot

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [`FCSA Number`](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/validate-and-format-numbers-in-angularjs/) to handle decimal input in AngularJS.

If I use the `maxDecimals` option it almost works as expected. For two decimals, inputs like "100.333" are transformed to "100.33".

In my region comma is used as decimal separator, but the input on my website should use dot as decimal separator -- like this plugin does. That's fine. However, I would like that input like "100,33" are converted to "100.33".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I am afraid I am unfamiliar with `FCSA number` :(

> However, if your goal is to understand how to implement a **simple**, **angular-oriented solution** that may well suit your needs, read on...
>   You will find below the `price` directive I implemented in a plunker. It is quite straightforward, and I recommend you take the time to study it, then implement your own solution, inspired by both the `price` directive and the `FCSA` source code.

---

1. a `filter` to convert comma numbers to decimal numbers:

   ```
   app.filter('comma2decimal', [
   function() { // should be altered to suit your needs
       return function(input) {
       var ret=(input)?input.toString().trim().replace(",","."):null;
           return parseFloat(ret);
       };
   }]);
   ```

This filter will automatically convert data from view format (with a comma) to model format (your scope, with a decimal).

---

2. a `filter` to convert decimal numbers to comma numbers:

   ```
   app.filter('decimal2comma', [
   function() {// should be altered to suit your needs
       return function(input) {
           var ret=(input)?input.toString().replace(".",","):null;
           if(ret){
               var decArr=ret.split(",");
               if(decArr.length>1){
                   var dec=decArr[1].length;
                   if(dec===1){ret+="0";}
               }//this is to show prices like 12,20 and not 12,2
           }
           return ret;
       };
   }]);
   ```

This filter will automatically convert data from model format (your scope, with a decimal) to view format (your view, with a comma).

---

3. a `directive` named **price** that uses those two filters:

   ```
   app.directive('price', ['$filter',
   function($filter) {
   return {
       restrict:'A',
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
           ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
               //convert data from view format to model format

               data=$filter('comma2decimal')(data);

               return data;
           });

           ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
               //convert data from model format to view format

               data=$filter('decimal2comma')(data);

               return data;
           });
       }
   };}]);
   ```

---

See [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pjqQMY?p=preview), showing how everything works together.

Initially, a number (e.g. coming from database) has a decimal value in controller scope ($scope.price=25.36;);

In the view, it appears like: 25,36 in the input, and 25.36, as in the database, below.

Now enter any comma number: it is automatically converted to decimal number for insertion in database.

Hoping this answers your question.

---

**Advantage of using a directive**: it is reusable, everywhere you need it on your website.

**Advantage of using two filters**: separation of concerns.

---

This approach lets users use numbers they are most used to in your views. 
However, the numbers entered can be altered in the background before insertion into database, so they are formatted properly.

And when you fetch prices/numbers from the database, they are automatically altered, before showing in the view in a way better suited to the reader.

If you need other options like in the `FCSA` Number directive, you can easily add them in your filters.

You will probably need custom functions and model validation, using `ngModelCtrl.$setValidity`.

Comment: note that this filters will return null for 0. This means if your model is set to the value 0 angular displays it as null (empty field). use `var ret=(input != void(0))?[...]` to display 0 too.

Comment: Look the @Sebastian Hindberg Berg answer!

Answer (score 23):

Add your corresponding locale:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.0/angular-locale_en-us.min.js"></script>
```

You can check the list of available locales here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n

Comment: This should be the correct and more standard answer

Comment: For french Canadians, make sure to choose the fr-ca option, not the ca-fr. It will give you a european currency if you pick this one.

Comment: This is the more easy and correct answer! not workaround

Answer (score 14):

You just need to use angular `number` filter and change angular's default separator and group characters.

```js
app.run(["$locale", function ($locale) {
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = " ";
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP = ".";
}]);
```

Then in your HTML:

```html
<p>{{ the_number | number:0 }}</p>
```

Comment: can u show example in how to implement this on ionic 3?? for example in .ts?

Comment: For South African Currency (ZAR), in my directive i had to add the above to get ng-currency - which uses the angular formatter - to display the currency in the official format: 
$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP = ",";
$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = "";
This allowed me to use ng-currency without having to hack the locale, which is not reliably used.

Answer (score 1):

I used an unorthodox solution. In the .js of Angular I looked for "DECIMAL_SEP" and changed:

```
DECIMAL_SEP:".",GROUP_SEP:","
```

to

```
DECIMAL_SEP:",",GROUP_SEP:"."
```

And it works! isn't the best solution but it works... I Just want to help.

PS. I'm from Colombia, sorry if my English is not well.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way:

```
app.filter('commaToDecimal', function(){
    return function(value) {
        return value ? parseFloat(value).toFixed(2).toString().replace('.', ',') : null;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
.filter('dot2comma', [
  function() {
    return function(value) {
      return value.toString().replace(/\./g,',');
    };
  }]);
```