# AngularJS number format in input element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

I need to localize my AngularJS to accept the decimal character ',' instead '.' in my inputs.

My current AngularJS looks like:

```
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
...
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
  <form ...>
    <input type="number" name="myNumber" ng-model="data.myNumber />
  </form>
</body>
```

In my application I require that the input shows the value like "123,45" but in the javascript I need the value to be a number like "123.45".

The problem, of course, is with IE and others browsers without support for decimal localization.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077210/angularjs-decimal-input-change-comma-to-dot

Comment: I like to use this: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks. You can do pretty much whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the input and parse it to a string.
2. Use string replace and replace the comma to a decimal

   3. convert back to number using parseFloat(numberHere);