# How To Total Sum Along With Comma Values in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to `total sum` along with `comma value` , actually I got the `total sum value` but the `comma value` is not `calculated`...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SLMSbNgUoLU7giZ7I9I?p=preview)   **For Example** :-  without comma `amt` values total sum answer I got 3850.20, then with `comma` of `amount payment`  values  total sum I got 2.00, Expecting like 3850.20  , If any one knows the solution help to us thanks....

**My controller:-**

```
    .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
})
```

**My Html:-**

```
<td >{{mani.amt}}</td>

  <td >{{mani.amount_payment }}</td>
```

**My Data:-**

```
    {
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "1,925.10",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},

{
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "1,925.10",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},
```

I have created Plunker for reference:- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SLMSbNgUoLU7giZ7I9I?p=preview)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077210/angularjs-decimal-input-change-comma-to-dot

You are using two locals, the '.' and the ',' as separators for your currency. Return the same currency format from server

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer , can you please update my plunker as well to know the solution .....

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/59JZdeJMj4lRDcDvIS5T?p=preview

Comment: hey hi, i have got calculation answer like 1,925.10...so can't change that in api ... so can you please provide the exact solution.... i know yours solution already... so please look into my plunker and help to us.... thanks.... how to calculate comma values in table?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should avoid storing/passing numbers after being formatted, so you should pass number `"amount_payment": "1,925.10"` as `"amount_payment": "1925.10"` (without comma), or even better as float: `"amount_payment": 1925.10`, on your views you can then format it with *Number*'s *toLocalString()* function: `(1925.10).toLocaleString()` or even `("1925.10").toLocaleString()`. In your case you can just remove commas when summing:

```
angular.forEach(data,function(v){
  sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key].replace(',', ''));
});
```

also you can use *reduce()* function to sum:

```
app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
  return function (data, key) {
    // debugger;
    if (!data || !data[0] || !data[0][key]) {
      return 0; 
    }

    var sum = data.reduce(function(sum, val) {
      return sum + parseFloat(val[key].replace(',', ''));
    }, 0);

    return sum.toFixed(2);
  }
})
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Hllaw254sBO2nbaZlKQ?p=preview

Comment: thanks for you valuable comment , can please provide updated plunker as well to know the exact solution .... thanks a lot...

Comment: added plunker link to my answer